# Weight Painting Issue: bones move parts of the mesh differently to others, even though I intend for them to move the same way

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I'm attempting to rig this gun to some bones
[image: Pictured: the Gun, as normal.]

However, when I paint the weights, the bone I connect it to, for some reason, screws with the Mesh, with some parts bugging out.

[image: Huh?]

Strange part is: I've not done anything wrong with the weight painting. As far as I know, this shouldn't be happening. [image: Pictured: a very red mesh, with no signs of improper painting.]

What's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The topology of your gun seems to be rather strange and part of it has inverted normals:

[image]

You can fix most of that by hitting <kbd>A</kbd> in Edit mode and then using <kbd>Shift-N</kbd> to recalculate the normals, but some faces are left inverted and need to be selected seperately and flipped with <kbd>Alt-N</kbd> > <kbd>Flip</kbd>. You also have 55 duplicate verts on the gun whcih you can fix with <kbd>M</kbd> > <kbd>Merge</kbd> > <kbd>By Distance</kbd> and it looks as if you have some overlapping faces too from the moire patterns you can see on some of the faces.

Try fixing all those and see if that sorts the problem.

Comment: I've done so, but it hasn't really helped much.

Comment: As I said, the overall topology of the gun looks wierd which probably won't help. It has verts and edges all over the place and some faces are just hanging in mid air so I've no idea how you modelled it. Without starting again from scratch, I'm not sure how you could sort it to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

To add to John Eason's answer: If we select a vertex of the part that goes wrong, you can see that it is part of some vertex groups it should not be. The consequence is that this part is influenced by several bones, not only the one it should be:

[image]

What you need to to is select this whole part, remove from all groups, then assign to the vertex group called *Bone* only:

[image]